# Cerberus is very slow for valdiation, what have I done wrong?

Tags: python, validation, performance-testing, cerberus, pydantic

**(Disclaimer: Every performance comparison on stackoverflow I read gets slammed for not being comprehensive/correct/well written/relevant etc. etc. - I'm not pretending this is a real comparison or perfectly setup, I would just like to know if I can make cerberus validate data more quickly.)**

I have the following model setup with [cerberus](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/):

```py
v = Validator({
    'id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
    'client_name': {'type': 'string', 'maxlength': 255, 'required': True},
    'sort_index': {'type': 'float', 'required': True},
    'client_phone': {'type': 'string', 'maxlength': 255, 'nullable': True},
    'location': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {'latitude': {'type': 'float'}, 'longitude': {'type': 'float'}},
        'nullable': True,
    },
    'contractor': {'type': 'integer', 'min': 0, 'nullable': True, 'coerce': int},
    'upstream_http_referrer': {'type': 'string', 'maxlength': 1023, 'nullable': True},
    'grecaptcha_response': {'type': 'string', 'minlength': 20, 'maxlength': 1000, 'required': True},
    'last_updated': {'type': 'datetime', 'nullable': True, 'coerce': datetime_parse},
    'skills': {
        'type': 'list',
        'default': [],
        'schema': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema': {
                'subject': {'type': 'string', 'required': True},
                'subject_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
                'category': {'type': 'string', 'required': True},
                'qual_level': {'type': 'string', 'required': True},
                'qual_level_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
                'qual_level_ranking': {'type': 'float', 'default': 0, 'required': True},
            },
        },
    },
})

...

def do_validation(data):
    validated = v.validated(data)
    if validated is None:
        return False, v.errors
    else:
        return True, validated
```

This is being used to validate data, roughly 50% of the data passes `do_validation`.

The problem is that cerberus is **extremely** slow when doing this validation, taking on average over a millisecond for each validation. For comparison this is over 10x slower than other libraries and 26x slower than [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) which I was benchmarking it against.

I wouldn't be surprised if cerberus was a little slower, but this difference seems too extreme to make sense.

Am I doing something wrong which is significantly harming performance?

---

The code above was written for the [benchmarks section](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/benchmarks/) of pydantic's docs.

The PR adding cerberus is (currently) open [here](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/987) with the full code and results.

Comment: Not an answer, not up-to-date either, but still quite interesting: [readthedocs - benchmarks - Why you should care about performance](https://validx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/benchmarks.html#why-you-should-care-about-performance) (found in a few first results of googling 'cerberus validator slow').